# Jquery ( Javascript ) id selector query

Tags: jquery

I saw an implementation of ID selector like this:

```
$("*[id*=foo]").val()
```

Why is this being used and is it similar to the id selector in jQuery? What is the main difference? Please explain

Comment: its the same. its just, that method is longer.

Comment: It's using attribute selector syntax: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ . Not necessary for IDs or classes because you can use the `#id` and `.class` syntaxes, but useful for selecting by other attributes

Comment: Using an attribute selector to select by `id` is usually a code smell that means there's duplicated `id` attributes in the DOM and the original dev was too lazy to fix it properly.

Comment: Ok, with the correct formatting, the question changed of meaning!

Comment: Agreed, now we can see the * it's a slightly different situation. There is a use case for this selector syntax in that scenario, to select items whose ID contains that text, so it could select multiple elements potentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

`$("*[id*=foo]").val()` isn't similar to `$("#foo").val()`:

- `$("#foo")` selects an element which `id` *is* “foo”.
- `$("*[id*=foo]")` selects any element which `id` attribute *contains* “foo”.

Check this example, where I used `input id="fooAndSomeText"`:

```js
console.log( $("*[id*=foo]").val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fooAndSomeText" value="bar" disabled />
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old answer**
*Before the question was formatted properly, changing its meaning!*

`$("[id=foo]").val()` and `$("#foo").val()` would do the exact same thing.
`#` is the shorthand to target an `id`.

The first syntax is longer here, and there is no reason to use it.

But, this syntax is very useful when you want to target an element with a specific attribute value. Check this example with an `input`:

```js
console.log( $("[name=foo]").val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="foo" value="bar" disabled />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AbhishekRenduchintala So you may want to tick my answer as correct. That's the proper way to say the problem is solved! :)